# How to set all pixels that are not in the list of allowed values to white?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an image that contains RGB pixels. I have a list of pixels `meaningful_pixels: List[Tuple(int, int, int)]` that I consider to be meaningful information and I want to set all other pixels to white `(255, 255, 255)`

This is the original image

[image]

and I'm trying to transform it to

[image]

I already successfully created list of "allowed pixels", which is the "purple-to-yellow" gradient of top-left rectangle, which is stored in `meaningful_pixels` variable, of shape (*num_of_pixels*, 3).

I am able to remove black rectangle by creating mask and using it to change pixels

```py
# actual code
mask = np.all(image == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
image[mask] = [255, 255, 255]
```

But I don't know how to create a mask when I have a list of values instead of one.

I was able to accomplish that with a for loop but the performance was pretty bad. I need help with accomplishing that with numpy "vectorized" approach for maximum performance. Something like:

```py
#pseudocode
image = np.remove_value_if_not_in_list(image, allowed_pixels)
```

## Solution

```py
# creates mask of "allowed pixels"
mask = np.all(np.isin(img, allowed_pixels) == [True, True, True], axis=-1)
# use inverted mask to replace pixels with white
img[~mask] = [255, 255, 255]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for similar processes.
I have combined this with [numpy.isin()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) as well, which would achieve what you want.

Code example something like:

```
import numpy as np

#pseudocode
image = np.where(np.isin(image, list_of_exlusions), image, mask_value)
```

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction with "isin(...)" function. I updated my original question with the solution.

Comment: no worries. ill look into the np.all next time I do something similar too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to take a Python function and apply it to an `ndarray` using broadcasting.

```py
def is_not_meaningful_pixel(pixel):
    return pixel not in meaningful_pixels

mask = np.vectorize(is_not_meaningful_pixel)(image)
image[mask] = (255, 255, 255)
```

Here's a more concrete example with data:

```py
BAD_VALUES = (2, 3, 4)
REPLACEMENT_VALUE = 99
data = np.arange(7)

def condition(val):
    return val in BAD_VALUES
vectorized_condition = np.vectorize(condition)

mask = vectorized_condition(data)
data[mask] = REPLACEMENT_VALUE

print(data)

# output
[ 0  1 99 99 99  5  6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sadly, vectorized functions are almost as slow as regular for loop and docs confirm that: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html